# Data import wizard error

Tags: leads, data-import-wizard

Hi one of my sales agents have a problem when importing leads into salesforce.
All other clients don't have that problem it's just her. I've tried everything to fix this problem but no luck.

The problem occurs when we import a .cvs file into the data import wizard. When the file is imported the mapping is wrong. Everything is shown in 1 row instead of multiple separated with the mark ;

See the image below:
[image]

Please Advise,
Darko

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem. Could you please share example of what are you trying to import? At least 2-3 first lines? Probably her CSV format is different, having \r or \n instead of \r\n or what is expected by Salesforce data import wizard?
Does this person has different operating system or different tool for creation of CSV files than those people who do not experience problems?

Comment: Hey Patlatus thank you for your fast reply, but i found the solution of my problem and post it as an answer. The problem was the keyboard input methods that didn't allowed that user to import the data correctly. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out after a while.
The problem:
Not able to import leads from .cvs file into Salesforce data import wizard. The mapping is showing in 1 row with ; separation, shown at the image above.

The solution to my problem is the following.
Navigate to *Start>Control Panel>Change Keyboard and other input methods*.
Region and Language window will open.Navigate to *Format* and press *Additional Settings*. The image below will show. Change it exactly at is shown in the image.
The problem was the *US* instead of *Metric* for **Measurement System** and *,* instead of *;* for **List Separator**.

[image]

Now it works like charm.

Regards,
Darko